# Dynamic id is getting added in sforce.one.navigateToURL("/home/home.jsp", true);

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, migration

I am using the below snippet in our code

```
if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) ) {
            sforce.one.navigateToURL("/home/home.jsp", true);
} else {
            window.location = link1;
}
```

In lightning when the page redirects some dynamic id is getting added in URL
one/one.app#eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJob21lOmxhbmRpbmciLCJhdHRyaWJ1dGVzIjp7fSwic3RhdGUiOnt9fQ%3D%3D

and It gives an error message: 'The page no longer exists. Try reloading it. If the problem persists, contact Salesforce support.

Could you please guide me??

Comment: I think the %3D in the end should be the cause of error. You Anchor point translates to base64 representation `eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJob21lOmxhbmRpbmciLCJhdHRyaWJ1dGVzIjp7fSwic3RhdGUiOnt9fQ==` which when decoded gives  `{"componentDef":"home:landing","attributes":{},"state":{}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to navigate to lightning home page, try:

```
sforce.one.navigateToURL("/lightning/page/home");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help